# Preserve element order when shredding XML data into SQL rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, xquery

How do I return the element sequence when shredding XML into rows in a SQL Server view?

Sample Input:

```
<ol>
  <li>Smith</li>
  <li>Jones</li>
  <li>Brown</li>
</ol>
```

Desired output:

```
Sequence  Name
--------  -----------
    1     Smith
    2     Jones
    3     Brown
```

Existing view:

```
CREATE VIEW OrderedList
AS
SELECT [Sequence] = CAST(NULL AS int)   -- TODO: Get ordinal position
       [Name] = b.b.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
FROM
(
    SELECT a = CAST('<ol><li>Smith</li><li>Jones</li><li>Brown</li></ol>' AS xml)
) a
CROSS APPLY a.a.nodes('/ol/li') b (b)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` on the xml node.

```
CREATE VIEW OrderedList
AS
SELECT [Sequence] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY b.b),
       [Name] = b.b.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
FROM
(
    SELECT a = CAST('<ol><li>Smith</li><li>Jones</li><li>Brown</li></ol>' AS xml)
) a
CROSS APPLY a.a.nodes('/ol/li') b (b)
```

Ref: [Uniquely Identifying XML Nodes with DENSE_RANK](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2009/08/03/uniquely-identifying-xml-nodes-with-dense-rank.aspx)  by Adam Machanic.